# Java : One thread needs to wait for other to be done

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following use case. Can anyone suggest a good implementation of method **t1()** assuming it would be run on JAVA 6 ? I tried to think of accomplishing this using wait() and notify() but could not get a proper solution. Any help will be appreciated. (Note that both of these methods **t1()** and **m1()** will be called in different threads)

```
 class Test
 {

   static volatile int flag = 0;

   public static void t1()
   {
           //This method will be called in a Thread called T2
           /*This method must wait for flag to become 1. As soon it
             becomes 1 this must return. However it should wait for maximum 
             n seconds. After that even if flag is 0 it must return.*/
   }



   public static void m1()
   {
           //This method will be called in a Thread called T1
           flag = 1;
   }
}
```

This is what I tried so far as implementation of t1()

```
   public static void t1() throws InterruptedException
   {
          while(flag == 0)
          {
               Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
          }
   }
```

Above works but problem is timeout is not implemented and while loop does not seem to be that good.

Comment: `java.util.concurrent` has everything you need.

Comment: both of them are being called on the same instance of Test from different thread ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Perhaps you could post a bit of code showing some basic synchronization.

Comment: You should try to look at using ThreadLocal for managing static threads during your application context.

Comment: Please show us what you're tried so far, otherwise this looks like a "make my homework" question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Initialize it before any of the threads run  with the count to one. Your code will then look something like this:

```
class Test
 {

   static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

   public static void t1()
   {
           //This method will be called in a Thread called T2
           /*This method must wait for flag to become 1. As soon it
             becomes 1 this must return. However it should wait for maximum 
             n seconds. After that even if flag is 0 it must return.*/
           latch.await(1L,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           //your remaining logic
   }



   public static void m1()
   {
          //your logic
          latch.countDown();
   }
}
```

A `CountDownLatch` is a somewhat modified, enhanced (e.g. timeout option), and arguably easier-to-understand implementation of a [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) - one of the basic structures used widely for thread synchronization across a number of languages (not only Java). Note the following when comparing the Wikipedia reference to the Java implementation:

- `P`/`wait()` corresponds to `await()`, with the difference that `await()` doesn't change the `count` value.
- `V`/`signal()` corresponds to `countDown()`, with the difference that `countDown()` counts **down**, not up (obviously).

Comment: Perfect! Seems like a flawless approach!

Comment: @snow_loeopard: glad that helped. I've made one style improvement and added some general reference for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CountDownLatch`

```
private static CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void t1() throws InterruptedException {
    countDownLatch.await(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("t2");
}

public static void m1() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("t1");

    // you can simulate some activity
    Thread.sleep(500);
    countDownLatch.countDown();
}
```

The thread running `t1()` will have to wait up to a second.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                test.Test.m1();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                test.Test.t1();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    });
    t2.start();
    t1.start();
}
```

This is a bad idea in a static context though as other classes will have access to it and may call the methods, which will screw up the latch.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion is essentially same as that of TheTerribleSwiftTomato. Unfortunately it seems I can nto select two correct answers. But nevertheless Thank you very much!

Comment: @snow_leopard You're welcome. Careful when using multithreaded operations in static contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You could **poll** until the condition is satisfied. Instead of using `Thread.sleep(long time)` between checks, I suppose it's more practical to just use `Thread.yield()`:

```
public static void t1()
{
    while (flag == 0)
    {
        Thread.yield();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Narrative complete example using `CountDownLatch`

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Race {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag=true; //set false to see other behavior
        if (flag) {
            startRace(5L, 2L);
        } else {
            startRace(2L, 5L);
        }
    }

    private static void startRace(final long s1, final long s2) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test.t1(s1);
            }
        }.start();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test.t2(s2);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

class Test {

    static volatile int flag = 0;

    static CountDownLatch L = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void t1(long n) {
        await(n);
        logic1();
        L.countDown(); // comment to wait till end

    }

    public static void t2(long n) {
        await(n);
        logic2();
        L.countDown();
    }

    private static void logic1() {
        if (flag == 0) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()
                    + ": Flag Couldnt be set in time");
        } else {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": Flag set in time");
        }
    }

    private static void logic2() {
        flag = 1;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": Flag Set");
    }

    private static void await(long n) {
        waitMsg(n);
        try {
            if (L.await(n, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                waitOverBefore(n);
            } else {
                waitOver(n);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void waitOverBefore(long n) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": Waiting Over before "
                + n + " seconds");
    }

    private static void waitOver(long n) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ":" + n
                + " seconds Waiting Over");
    }

    private static void waitMsg(long n) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ":Waiting for " + n
                + " seconds");
    }

}
```

Output 1

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:Waiting for 5 seconds
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:Waiting for 2 seconds
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:2 seconds Waiting Over
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]: Flag Set
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Waiting Over before 5 seconds
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Flag set in time
```

Output 2

```
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:Waiting for 5 seconds
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:Waiting for 2 seconds
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:2 seconds Waiting Over
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Flag Couldnt be set in time
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]: Waiting Over before 5 seconds
Thread[Thread-1,5,main]: Flag Set
```